# How to get annotation metadata of spring beans

Tags: java, spring

In my spring project I have multiple implementations of an interface.

```
interface Car {

}

@Component
@ColorOptions({Color.RED})
class SportsCar implements Car {

}

class Truck implements Car {

}

@Configuration
class CarConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @ColorOptions({Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE})
    public Truck oldTruck() {
        return new Truck();
    }

    @Bean
    @ColorOptions({Color.BLUE})
    public Truck newTruck() {
        return new Truck();
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to create a spring bean which would be a `Map` containing all the implementations of the interface which would be grouped based on the metadata provided in the `ColorOptions` annotation.

```
    @Bean
    public Map<Color, List<Car>> groupedCars(List<Car> cars) {
        // ???
        return null;
    }
```

The `org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory#findAnnotationOnBean` provides an option to do it but I was able only to receive the values only in case I annotated a class. In case of spring beans which were defined in methods I do not get anything. Also I would like to avoid injecting the whole `ApplicationContext` and inject just the implementations of the interface. How can I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

1. get BeanDefinition

```
BeanDefinition beanDefinition =applicationContext.getBeanDefinition("beanName");
```

2. get AnnotatedTypeMetadata

```
 MergedAnnotation< ColorOptions > tenantFunMergedAnnotation = ((AnnotatedTypeMetadata) beanDefinition.getSource()).getAnnotations().get(ColorOptions.class);
```

Comment: OP asked a way t do this without injecting the applicationContext

Answer (score 0):

You can  use java refection to iterate through the methods

```
public class RunCarConfiguration {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Testing grouped car ...");
    Class<CarConfiguration> obj = CarConfiguration.class;

    // Process @ColorOption
    if (obj.isAnnotationPresent(ColorOptions.class)) {
        Annotation annotation = obj.getAnnotation(ColorOptions.class);
        ColorOptions colorOptions = (ColorOptions) annotation;

        System.out.printf("%nColor :%s", colorOptions.color());
        System.out.printf("%nLastModified :%s%n%n",
                colorOptions.lastModified());

    }


Map <ColorOptions.Color, Car> groupedCar = new HashMap<ColorOptions.Color, Car>();
    // Process @Test
    for (Method method : obj.getDeclaredMethods()) {

        // if method is annotated with @Test
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(ColorOptions.class)) {
            Annotation annotation = obj.getAnnotation(ColorOptions.class);
            ColorOptions colorOptions = (ColorOptions) annotation;

            try {
                method.invoke(obj.newInstance());
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent(ColorOptions.class)) {
                    System.out.printf("Test '%s' - has method annnotation %s %n" ,
                            method.getReturnType().getName(), 
                            method.getAnnotation(ColorOptions.class).color());
                    groupedCar.put( method.getAnnotation(ColorOptions.class).color(),
                            (Car)method.invoke(obj.newInstance()));
                }

            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                System.out.printf("Test '%s' - failed: %s %n" ,
                        method.getName(), ex.getCause());
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: It would be possible to do it this way in case all the spring beans implementing `Car` interface are defined in the `CarConfiguration` class. You miss here the `SporstCar` bean. But in my case I need a better solution. Here are the two other problems: 
1. The spring beans might be defined in different modules
2. The `ColorOption` annotation is used also used on beans which do not implement the `Car` interface

Comment: You could try ComponentScan see if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ComponentScan

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION,
    classes = ColorOption.class))
public class ComponentScanAnnotationFilterApp { }
```

Comment: `ComponentScan` will only telll what should be managed by Spring. In my project I need to have in my application context also beans which are not annotated with the `ColorOption` annotation and even if all my beans would be annotated with it I still don't know how would I be able to group them into a `Map`